# redirecting whole domain to another and not just a single page in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my whole website to a new domain. for example
url:"http://www.example-domain.com/contact" redirect to "https://www.example.com/contact". so every url redirect to new url like "example.com/whateveritwas".I don't know how to write rewrite rules in web.config. hope you can help me with this .thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are using IIS you should be looking to implement Application Request Routing which is available for IIS 7 onwards. ARR allow's you to reverse proxy incoming requests based on pattern matches (rewrite rules) and relay to your target host. A word of warning, I have had issues routing without using an ARR WebFarm so strongly suggest that you use one even for a single target host.

ARR 2.0 IIS 7 - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-(arr)/install-application-request-routing-version-2

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx